# using sequence in Dynamic sql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a dynamic sql :

```
forall k in 1..Job_ID.COUNT Save exceptions
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into XYZ values(:1,:2,:3)' using sequence_one.NextVal,job_id(k),Name(k);
 ///Exception handling.
```

On running the abouve query only one row is getting inserted.And following error is thrown:

```
ORA-24381: error(s) in array DML.
```

Any idea why above thing is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really want every inserted row to have the same sequence value in the first column?  If not you should do this:

```
forall k in 1..Job_ID.COUNT Save exceptions
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into XYZ values(sequence_one.NextVal,:2,:3)'
    using job_id(k),Name(k);
```

Or even better (unless you have a good reason for using dynamic SQL:

```
forall k in 1..Job_ID.COUNT Save exceptions
  insert into XYZ values(sequence_one.NextVal, job_id(k), Name(k));
```